# Defining which widget determines the height of the parent widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to design a basic flutter website that has a list of scrollable items and then a dotted line to the left of them. However the dotted line class that I got from Chatgpt, required a height input. I want it to dynamically just use the height of however many elements there will be however, that is proving to be more difficult than expected.

Here is the important bit of code:

```
var widgetsFinal = <Widget>[
      const MenuBar(),
      Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 0,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: VerticalDottedLinePainter(
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(135, 235, 240, 1),
                      strokeWidth: 2,
                      gapSize: 30),
                  size: const Size(2, double.infinity),
                  // Set line width to 2 and height to maximum available height
                ),
              ),
              //
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: drinkWidgets,
                  ))
            ],
          )),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.black, child: Column(children: widgetsFinal)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The VerticalDottedLinePainter is throwing an error since it says double.infinity in a row is not allowed even though I know it will be constrained by the expanded column of drinkWidgets.

How do I fix this?

Comment: can you include simplified minimal full widget that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what VerticalDottedLinePainter and DrinkWidgets are, but I think it would be good to wrap CustomPaint with a Container and give it a constraints option.

like below.

```
               ...
               Expanded(
                  flex: 0,
                  child: Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      ),
                      height: double.infinity,
                      child: CustomPaint(
                      painter: VerticalDottedLinePainter(
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(135, 235, 240, 1),
                          strokeWidth: 2,
                          gapSize: 30
                          ),
                      size: const Size(2, double.infinity),
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
             ...
```

I know roughly what you want, but I don't think the code above should allow heigiht to have an infinite value in Row at the bottom of menuBar().
I think it's right to limit it and make it take up as much as possible.

Comment: This removes the error but does not stretch to fit the entire list of items